# Ошибка vk_api __call__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Tags: python, api, вконтакте, бот

```
# Импорт модулей
import vk_api
import random
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id


# Залетаем и регаемся как бот
token = "deleted_by_security_reasons"
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk)

# А это для призыва
vkBotSession = VkApi(token=token)
vk = vkBotSession.get_api()





# Упрощаем процесс вывода сообщений
def write_msg(user_id, message):
    vk.method('messages.send', {'user_id': user_id, 'message': message, 'random_id': random.randint(0, 200000)})

# Сам процесс
for event in longpoll.listen():

    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:

        if event.to_me:

            request = event.text

            if request == "привет":
                write_msg(event.user_id, "Привет! Как жизнь?")
            elif "как дела" in request:
                write_msg(event.user_id, "Все круто! У тебя как?")
            elif "крут" in request:
                write_msg(event.user_id, "О да, это точно круто! ")
            elif "всем" in request and "хорошего" in request and "дня" in request:
                write_msg(event.user_id, "И тебе хорошего дня! ")
            if "разбуди всех" in request:
                prizyv()





# Сама функция призыва
def prizyv():
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id=2000000013,
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Призыв!'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

    vk.messages.send(
        peer_id=2000000013,
        message=message,
        random_id=get_random_id()
    )
```

Выводит:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Jason.py", line 40, in <module>
    write_msg(event.user_id, "О да, это точно круто! ")
  File "Jason.py", line 24, in write_msg
    vk.method('messages.send', {'user_id': user_id, 'message': message, 'random_id': random.randint(0, 200000)})
TypeError: __call__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

В чем может быть проблема? И как исправить эту проблему?

Также он не отвечает на сообщения в беседах, только в личку. Листал форумы но ответа решающего моего проблему не нашел.

новый код:

```
# Импорт модулей
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id


# функция ответа
def send_message(peer_id, message):
    vk.messages.send(
        peer_id=peer_id,
        message=message,
        random_id=get_random_id(),
    )

# функция призыва
def prizyv():
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id=2000000013,
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Призыв!'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

    vk.messages.send(
        peer_id=2000000013,
        message=message,
        random_id=get_random_id()
    )

# Залетаем и регаемся как бот
token = "mytoken"
groupId = '183464879'
vkBotSession = VkApi(token=token)
longPoll = VkBotLongPoll(vkBotSession, groupId)
vk = vkBotSession.get_api()

# Ответ на сообщения
for event in longPoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        from_id = event.obj['from_id']
        peer_id = event.obj['peer_id']
        message = event.obj['text']

        if 'привет' in message:
            send_message(peer_id, 'Привет! Как жизнь?')
        elif 'как дела' in message:
            send_message(peer_id, 'Круто! У тебя как?')
        elif 'крут' in message:
            send_message(peer_id, 'О да, это точно круто! B-)')
        elif 'Призыв!' == message and peer_id == 504785497:
            prizyv()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это из-за `VkLongPoll`.

В [документации](https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/longpoll.html) указано, что это модуль ***для пользователей***.
Так как Вы авторизуетесь с ключом ***сообщества***, Вам требуется `VkBotLongPoll`.
Обратите внимание, что он в другом модуле, а именно в `vk_api.bot_longpoll`.

Также советую отправлять сообщения, используя объект, полученный методом `get_api`.

***Пример (UPD 2):***

```py
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id


def send_message(peer_id, message):
    vk.messages.send(
        peer_id=peer_id,
        message=message,
        random_id=get_random_id(),
    )


def prizyv():
    # Не забудьте, для этого метода боту нужны права администратора!
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id=2000000013,
    )['items']

    # Отрицательный id у нашего и других ботов, их не учитываем
    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Призыв!'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        # Кстати, подходят даже некоторые невидимые символы, например:
        # message += f'[id{member_id}|ᅠ]'
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

    send_message(2000000013, message)


# Замените токен на свой!
accessToken = '...'
groupId = 183464879

vkBotSession = VkApi(token=accessToken)
longPoll = VkBotLongPoll(vkBotSession, groupId)
vk = vkBotSession.get_api()

for event in longPoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        """
        Если бот не отвечает на сообщения из беседы, то выдайте ему права
        на чтение всей переписки, а лучше сразу права администратора,
        потому что они нужны для функции prizyv. Я проверил, бот точно
        отвечает с необходимыми правами как в беседе, так и в ЛС.
        """
        from_id = event.obj['from_id']  # id пользователя, который отправил сообщение
        peer_id = event.obj['peer_id']  # peer_id беседы или ЛС, откуда пришло сообщение

        # lower - это метод приведения к нижнему регистру. Для регистронезависимости.
        message = event.obj['text'].lower()

        # message теперь в нижнем регистре, поэтому все проверки делаем тоже в нижнем регистре
        if 'привет' in message:
            send_message(peer_id, 'Привет! Как жизнь?')
        elif 'как дела' in message:
            send_message(peer_id, 'Круто! У тебя как?')
        elif 'крут' in message:
            send_message(peer_id, 'О да, это точно круто! B-)')
        elif message == 'призыв!' and from_id == 504785497:  # Здесь у Вас была ошибка. Вы сравнивали peer_id, вместо from_id
            prizyv()
```

Не забудьте про права и токен.

Comment: а теперь я не совсем понял как организовать так чтобы он отвечал на кодовые слова, и например я (с определенным айди) пишу в беседу ключевое слово и бот запускает функцию prizyv() . С эхо то понятно, просто я тут все переделал и другая ошибка выводит что таких то функций в VkBotEventType нету, а если вставить просто VkEventType то бот молчит

Comment: @WazzzUp Я обновил ответ, приблизив его к модели Вашего кода. Но до конца так и не понимаю, чего Вы хотите добиться. Поясните, пожалуйста, какая ошибка у Вас возникает и при чём тут `VkBotEventType`.

Comment: @WazzzUp Если Вам нужны дополнительные проверки, то воспользуйтесь информацией из `event.obj`. Так, например, поле `from_id` содержит `id` человека, который отправил сообщение. Можете сверять его со своим для идентификации.

Comment: Если хотите, мы можем [продолжить обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97284/).

Comment: Спасибо, все работает. Только как его сделать нечувствительным к регистру? и сделать так чтобы я не только ему в лс отсылал а писал в беседе "Призыв!" и он запускал эту функцию. Я отредактировал вопрос, там же мой новый код

Comment: @WazzzUp Ваша ошибка была в том, что Вы сравнивали свой `id` с `peer_id`, а нужно было с `from_id`. А регистронезависимость можно достичь сравнениями в нижнем регистре. Я обновил и постарался максимально сильно прокомментировать код, чтобы не осталось вопросов. Но если они есть - не стесняйтесь и спрашивайте, буду рад помочь.

Comment: Вы меня очень выручили! Спасибо вам огромное!

Comment: @WazzzUp В таком случае, пожалуйста, отметьте ответ как верный (нажмите на галочку около ответа). Это же можете сделать и с другим Вашим вопросом. Для меня это лучшая благодарность.

Comment: У меня еще один вопрос))) Я хочу вызывать функцию prizyv в 9 часов утра каждый день. Мне это нужно сделать через schedule? Или есть более простые методы как сделать это

Comment: @WazzzUp Я бы рекомендовал `schedule`.